# Where is the actual file for a module?

Tags: python

I apparently have multiple versions of a module installed and I am trying to figure out where the files are because only one of them is from package management and I want to delete the other.

Is there a simple way to ask Python where it found a module after importing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the module isn't built-in, you can do this:

```
import your_module
print(your_module.__file__)
```

test:

```
>>> import os
>>> print(os.__file__)
L:\Python34\lib\os.py
```

if module is built-in, you get an error:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.__file__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
>>>
```

(check if module has the `__file__` attribute using `hasattr` is also an option to avoid errors; `if hasattr(module_name, '__file__'):`)

also: by directly printing the module:

```
>>> print(os)
<module 'os' from 'L:\\Python34\\lib\\os.py'>
```

Comment: doing just `print module` it's a little bit more "elegant" and still useful
`import os; print os` prints `<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>` and `import sys; print sys` prints `<module 'sys' (built-in)>`

Comment: Might be worth adding `if hasattr(module_name, '__file__'):`

Comment: good suggestions. I hope you don't mind me editing my answer with those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__file__` after importing the module:

```
>>> import os 
>>> os.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'
```